# fetch all the unique record from table

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I have an mysql query.
I need fetch the all **"eid"** where **"aid"** not equal to **"15"**. My table is like below. The result should be in group. Example if **aid != 15** then We should get only **"eid"** = **3** and **4**.

```
id | eti | aid | eid | val
1  |  2  |  15 |  1  |  WDC
2  |  2  |  11 |  1  |  USA
3  |  2  |  9  |  1  |  XYX
4  |  2  |  15 |  2  |  LDN
5  |  2  |  11 |  2  |  UK
6  |  2  |  9  |  2  |  ABC
7  |  2  |  11 |  3  |  China
8  |  2  |  9  |  3  |  HNB
9  |  2  |  18 |  4  |  China
10 |  2  |  12 |  4  |  HNB
```

Anybody help me? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried something ? Your sentence nearly gives you the answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
select eid
from your_table
group by eid
having sum(aid = 15) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The query below should help you:

```
select 'aid' from 'table'
  where 'eid' not in
    (select 'eid' from 'table'
       where 'aid'='15')
  group by 'eid';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword. Your query will become:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(eid) FROM <Your_table_name> WHERE aid != 15
```